# HTTPS sending sensitive data

Tags: security, ssl

I have two different servers one serving desktop users and the other one serving mobile users. (`www.mywebsite.com`, `m.mywebsite.com`).

Users on mobile server need to send some **sensitive** data to `www` server for processing. So in `www` server I have installed an SSL. I am wondering if SSL certificate is also needed in `mobile` server so that the sensitive data can be transferred securely? Or just one server with SSL should suffice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary that not only the transfer of the sensitive data is protected by SSL but also anything leading to this transfer. If this is not the case one could use tools like [sslstrip](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work) to do an active man in the middle attack and replace any `https://` targets with `http://` targets without being the victim aware of it. 
And then the attacker could just intercept the plain data (i.e. http not https) and forward these with https to the original server.